# What is difference between Flux and Redux framework?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

On my Angular JS preparation; I came to know about ReactJS which is built on top of Flux and then heard about Redux. Now wondering how AngularJS related to ?

Answer (score 3):

React is not built on top of flux. Flux is a *pattern* (and later, the `facebook/flux` repo was created as an *implementation* of that pattern) for handling global application state, and is not specific to React, but works well with React's "state trickles from the top" philosophy. It was also developed at Facebook to be used with React.

Redux is a (different) JavaScript library for managing global application state changes, and shares some similarities with the flux design pattern, but is ultimately a different thing entirely.

None of these things have any direct relation to AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks Michelle. Good explanation.

Comment: This should be set as the answer